# Showing stacktrace or line number on Python error

Tags: python, intellij-idea, robotframework

I am running Robot test cases in IntelliJ. When there is a Python failure the line number is in the log.html file. How do I get the failure in the Run editor so I don't have to open a browser to find the error?

Comment: Please share the snippet of code that your are running.

Comment: may be you are looking for `log to console`

Answer (score 1):

I have a small [listener](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-version-2) for such purpose, implementing the `log_message` function.

In this function I call the `Log To Console` keyword and redirect everything to the console.

Example with Listener API 3 (RedirectLogsToConsole.py):

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 3

def log_message(message):
    BuiltIn().log_to_console(message)
```

Output for `robot --pythonpath ./ --loglevel DEBUG --listener RedirectLogsToConsole.py test.robot`

[image]

`pythonpath` argument is used because I do not have this listener in PYTHONPATH. Log level is changed to DEBUG to show traces in the log. Listener is invoked via the `--listener` argument.